# JBoss/Keycloak - Running Cluster in Azure

Tags: azure, jboss, cluster-computing, keycloak

I'm having trouble booting JBoss/Keycloak cluster in Azure using 2 CentOS virtual machines running latest Keycloak instance (Standalone HA mode). The cluster does not join together with following error message:

**Slave**

```
WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) ew-sit-idm-app01dc:
JOIN(ew-sit-idm-app01dc) sent to ew-sit-idm-app02 timed out (after 3000 ms), on try 1
```

**Master**

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.protocol.UDP] (TransferQueueBundler,ejb,ew-sit-idm-app02)
JGRP000032: ew-sit-idm-app02: no physical address for 1f285ecd-2f08-9b5f-6897-69ee5d871d78, dropping message
```

Here's the configuration:

```
<stack name="udp">
    <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp">
        <property name="ip_mcast">
            false
        </property>
    </transport>
    <protocol type="azure.AZURE_PING">
        <property name="storage_account_name">
            {storage}
        </property>
        <property name="storage_access_key">
            {access}
        </property>
        <property name="container">
            keycloak-ping
        </property>
    </protocol>
    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
    <protocol type="FD"/>
    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2">
        <property name="use_mcast_xmit">
            false
        </property>
        <property name="use_mcast_xmit_req">
            false
        </property>
    </protocol>
    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
    <protocol type="UFC"/>
    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
</stack>
```

Could you help me resolve these? The machines are within the same Virtual Network and Subnet, with all ports allowed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try TCP instead of UDP just in case multicast isnt supported?

Comment: Try to check if your machines are given correct host-names.